# Node-oracledb's createPool Method without SYSDBA

Tags: node.js

I met a obstacle when using node-oracledb's createPool method. Detailed description:

1. Created a table in Oracle 12c using SYSDBA privilige (Table name: guest)
2. Input some records into "guest" table.
3. Confirmed the input records are available with "commit" and "select" command in Windows 7 command
4. Wrote code as below:

   ```
   var oracledb = require("oracledb");
       (async ()=>{
           try{
               await oracledb.createPool({
                   _enableStats: true,
                   user: '[username]',//my username in database
                   password: '[password]',  //my password in database
                   connectString: 'localhost/orcl',
                   poolAlias: "chougou",
              });
              var connection =  await oracledb.getPool('chougou').getConnection();
              var result = await connection.execute('select * from guest');
              await connection.close();
              console.log(result)
          }catch(err){
              console.log(err.message)
          }
    })();
   ```

The result shows:

```
ORA-00942  Table or View do not exist
```

But, if I changed the select sentence to connection.execute('select * from dual'), I could get the normal result.

I analyzed above, and got the  conclusion: In oracledb.createPool{()}, it must exist one connection privilige attribution like  _enableStats:  user:  password: connectString: to connect Database with SYSDBA.

As my experience, in PHP, we can use  $session_mode in oci_connect() to give a privilige for connecting.

Could anyone help me to find this attribution in oracledb.createPool{()}?

Chen

chougou1982@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Regarding terminology, what you did was create a table as a user who happened to have SYSDBA system privileges.  As a guess that user was `SYS`.
- Fundamentally you shouldn't be creating user tables as SYS.  Create another user.
- You wouldn't want to be creating a whole pool of users in node-oracledb with such a high privilege level as SYSDBA because of the security implications.
- You can only use [`privilege`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#privconn) with standalone connections in node-oracledb.
- You could grant access to other users to read or update the table.  But see the second point above.

Comment: If you don't want to take my word against using SYS, check this post from one of the https://asktom.oracle.com/ people: https://twitter.com/connor_mc_d/status/1277476467035652097

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has been solved. According to your suggestion, I deleted all tables which were created by SYSDBA privilege, and then I created a new account and grant connection, resource,dba to [account]. After that, I use"conn [account]/[password]" to login in, and create the table and insert some records to it. In the end, I tested the code without any modification, and found that I could get the normal records. Thank you again for giving me a crrect direction to solve the problem!  Chen Chao  chougou1982@hotmail.com, 15021734016@139.com from Shanghai/China

Comment: Hi Chritopher Jones,

Comment: Hi Chritopher Jones, last time so thanks for your help. I meet one problems in Node.js blog developping. On LinkedIn, I send a message to you and hope your acception for communicate. My aim is to learn Node.js and deeply study some new skills on Web developping. Due to my database platform, so I think you are the expert on Oracle Database develop.

Comment: The best places to ask questions are here and on https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues